# Email notifications for updates

Tags: support, status-completed

Can we have email notifications similar to facebook? Its very hard to keep logged into stackexchange site waiting for relevant questions to come or to wait for answers for questions we post. Ultimately it may result in lowering of interest. Also all the time keeping logged in results in decreased productivity at work(I am kind of getting addicted). If we have a system of email notification(which may be controlled by proper settings), I think we will see increased response from people. People can select what subject( tags) they like to answer and chose them in the settings. This will inform them as soon as a question of their interest is posted on site.

Also it will be great if we can answer/comment just by emailing (as done in fb). This will reduce the response time.

Answer (score 2):

There are limited email notification available already, and the topic has been [discussed heavily on the mother meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=email%20notification). You will find that the official policy is to use email as a backup form of communication, not as a [substitute for visiting the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600).

Consider using [the RSS feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25224/email-notifications-for-new-questions-matching-specific-tags/25225#25225) (available at the bottom of most pages on the site) to follow sites/questions/tags/users that interest you.